# Error :: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V

Tags: java, eclipse, google-cloud-platform, jar

I am getting this error because I have ValidationFramework.jar which contains the same class as Google Cloud Platform Libraries i.e. com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState() and eclipse is choosing the class in ValidationFramework for my java application.

Can anyone tell me how to make eclipse choose Google Cloud Platform library for my java service?

Comment: Mention the complete error details here.

Answer (score 2):

Very likely one of your dependencies uses old Guava. `com.google.common.base.Preconditions` class is in Guava library (`com.google.guava:guava`). You have an unexpected version of Guava in your class path. If you can share your pom.xml or build.gradle, I can check further.